# Are Verma modules universally characterised?

Tags: ct.category-theory, rt.representation-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of Verma Module in wikipedia. It later goes to show that it satisfies what appears to be a universal property (which I'm also having trouble understanding - the page is a notational mess). Surely this can be taken as the definition? And is there a clear way of expressing it?

Comment: Well, why is this question down-voted ? Is it due to improper question framing ? 

Comment: I'm glad someone asked, I feared it impolite to ask myself :)

Comment: Mozibur, here are some things that would in my opinion improve your question.  (1) Link to the wikipedia article.  (2) Say where you've looked other than wikipedia: people taking the time to answer a question want to know that the person asking it has already made a serious effort.  (3) What exactly is the universal property that the you think Verma modules satisfy, and what exactly do you not understand?  (4) Clarify "Surely this can be taken as the definition?": you can't take a univ property as a definition unless you somehow know that something with that property exists. 

Comment: PS - It's not impolite to ask why your question is downvoted or closed.  Asking good questions takes skill, care and time, and regulars here will often be happy to explain how you can (in their opinion) improve them.  

Comment: @Leinster: Thanks for the suggestions; I'll amend appropriately. (Had it been not so far into the small hours, I would have done so when I wrote it.)  

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah : There is nothing impolite in asking about the down-votes, and your silence leads to more of such down-votes, as its said, a stitch in time , saves nine ! so its important that you ask , accept suggestions and re-frame your question accordingly as per the environment, I saw many worthy questions down-voted , for small reasons, and hence I asked it . Anyway I totally agree with @Tom Leinster, and I am just repeating what he said 

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah: 1) For an elementary textbook definition, you might better start with math.stackexchange.com.   But aside from that, you can't expect to study graduate-level mathematics without some library access (paper, online) plus some experience locating material online.
Wikipedia by itself is not enough.  There are textbook sources for concepts like "Verma module", but also online lecture notes (e.g., by Dennis Gaitsgory at Harvard).  2) The notion of Verma module involves both construction and characterization (existence and uniqueness), both straightforward apart from style.

Comment: @Shanmukha_Srinivasan: My silence has more to with getting a job than anything else:). It would probably have been better to have waited until my circumstances were a bit more stable. The question popped into my head sometime after I first learnt about Lie Groups/Algebras, and I ran across Verma Module on Wikipedia, and that in itself is a while ago. (I used Dragon Milicic online notes which I found very useful). I agree with Tom Leinsters comments too.

Comment: @Humphreys: Thanks for the online reference. I do realise that a universal construction is only for characterisation, and automatically proves uniqueness, so long as existence is shown. I have online access, but not a useful library access, unfortunately. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be too optimistic to hope for reconciliation of Wikipedia with reality, but, nevertheless, the issue is probably here-to-stay. The universal highest-weight module $V_\lambda$ with given highest weight $\lambda$ is indeed describable be the expected universal mapping proprty, that it has a unique reasonable map to any Lie algebra module generated by a highest weight vector with that weight.

This is version of Frobenius reciprocity...

Since such a module is anticipated to be "induced", it is not surprising that it admits a *construction* via tensor products and such.

But, yes, sometimes the Wikipedia descriptions are ... too immediate... although one could have imagined that this increases accessibility.